# How to add constraint that one generic type implements another generic type in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, type-bounds

How can I make something like this work:

```
struct FooStruct<A, B> where A : B, B : ?Sized {...}
```

I searched for some type marker to tell the compiler that `S` must be a trait, searched the Rust documentation for some example of this pattern, and couldn't find other people having the same problem. Here is my code:

```
trait Factory<S> where S : ?Sized {
    fn create(&mut self) -> Rc<S>;
}

trait Singleton<T> {
    fn create() -> T;
}

struct SingletonFactory<T> {
    instance: Option<Rc<T>>
}

impl<S, T> Factory<S> for SingletonFactory<T> where S : ?Sized, T : S + Singleton<T> {
    fn create(&mut self) -> Rc<S> {
        if let Some(ref instance_rc) = self.instance {
            return instance_rc.clone();
        }
        let new_instance = Rc::new(T::create());
        self.instance = Some(new_instance.clone());
        new_instance
    }
}
```

The compiler fails with the following error :

```
      --> src/lib.rs:15:57
   |
15 | impl<S, T> Factory<S> for SingletonFactory<T> where T : S + Singleton<T> {
   |                                                         ^ not a trait
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find an answer: the [`std::marker::Unsize<T>` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html), although not a stable feature in the current version of Rust (1.14.0).

> ```
> pub trait Unsize<T> where T: ?Sized { }
> ```
>
> Types that can be "unsized" to a dynamically-sized type.

This is broader than the "implements" semantic, but it is what I should have been searching for from the beginning, as the generic parameters in the example code can be other things than a struct and a trait or two traits (say sized and unsized arrays).

The generic example in the question can be written:

```
struct FooStruct<A, B>
    where A: Unsize<B>,
          B: ?Sized,
{
    // ...
}
```

And my code :

```
impl<S, T> Factory<S> for SingletonFactory<T>
    where S: ?Sized,
          T: Unsize<S> + Singleton<T>,
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `Unsize`, it certainly opens up new doors!

Comment: Yes, it was deeply hidden in the documentation :) This RFC provides some informations about it : https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0401-coercions.md. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Thanks again for digging up `Unsize`, enjoy SO ad-free ;)

Comment: Thanks, that's very nice :)